# split data into training and testing

Tags: python, machine-learning, training-data

I want to replicate this tutorial to classify two groups  https://machinelearningmastery.com/develop-n-gram-multichannel-convolutional-neural-network-sentiment-analysis/ with different dataset but could not do that despite being hardly trying. I am new to programming so would appreciate any assistance or tips that could help.

My dataset is small (240 files for each group), and files named 01 - 0240.

It is around these lines of codes, I think.

```
    if is_trian and filename.startswith('cv9'):
        continue
    if not is_trian and not filename.startswith('cv9'):
        continue
```

and also these

```
            trainy = [0 for _ in range(900)] + [1 for _ in range(900)]
            save_dataset([trainX,trainy], 'train.pkl')

            testY = [0 for _ in range(100)] + [1 for _ in range(100)]
            save_dataset([testX,testY], 'test.pkl')
```

two errors were encountered so far:

> Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays.
>   Found 483 input samples and 200 target samples.
>
> Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = 'model.h5', errno =
>   2, error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 0, o_flags =
>   0)

I would really appreciate any prompt help.

Thanks in advance.

//
Part of the code for more clarity.
//

```
# load all docs in a directory
def process_docs(directory, is_trian):
    documents = list()
    # walk through all files in the folder
    for filename in listdir(directory):
        # skip any transcript in the test set
```

I want to add an argument below to indicate whether to process the training or testing files, just as mentioned in the tutorial. Or if there's another 
    way please share it

```
        if is_trian and filename.startswith('----'):
            continue
        if not is_trian and not filename.startswith('----'):
            continue
        # create the full path of the file to open
        path = directory + '/' + filename
        # load the doc
        doc = load_doc(path)
        # clean doc
        tokens = clean_doc(doc)
        # add to list
        documents.append(tokens)
    return documents

# save a dataset to file
def save_dataset(dataset, filename):
    dump(dataset, open(filename, 'wb'))
    print('Saved: %s' % filename)

# load all training transcripts
healthy_docs = process_docs('PathToData/healthy', True)
sick_docs = process_docs('PathToData/sick', True)
trainX = healthy_docs + sick_docs
trainy = [0 for _ in range(len( healthy_docs ))] + [1 for _ in range(len( sick_docs ))]
save_dataset([trainX,trainy], 'train.pkl')

# load all test transcripts
healthy_docs = process_docs('PathToData/healthy', False)
sick_docs = process_docs('PathToData/sick', False)
testX = healthy_docs + sick_docs
testY = [0 for _ in range(len( healthy_docs ))] + [1 for _ in range(len( sick_docs ))]

save_dataset([testX,testY], 'test.pkl')
```

Comment: The code you provided is for the tutorial, which has 1800 train files and 200 test files. You have 240 files which is why you are getting the first error. Also, in the tutorial it is assumed that the negative reviews are the first 900 and the positive reviews the last 900. How are the positive and negative reviews distributed in your dataset? If you don't know then you are just assigning random target labels to any file.

Comment: Yes actually you are right, and hence I am trying to modify the code to suit my dataset. Negative and positive values will be assigned to the two groups in my dataset, negative for healthy people and positive for patients.

Comment: I don't think your error happens in the lines you have mentioned. It seems like you are giving the model 483 data and only 200 labels. but I'm not sure why that happens since I can't see all your code.

Comment: Thanks, Bahman. I have two separated folders for each group with 240 files for each group >> I realized that I had a few files more in one group just after your comment. I am using almost the same code used in the tutorial, but struggling to split my data into training and testing 90 - 10. I am not sure about the lables, but seems to be an issue with my code modifications.

Comment: So basically I need to put 24 files from each group as test sets, and the remaining files as a training dataset. I believe that I need to modify the above-mentioned lines of codes to achieve that. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You should post more of your code, but it sounds like your problem is curating the data. Say you have 240 files in a folder called 'healthy' and 240 files in a folder called 'sick'. Then you need to label all the healthy people with label 0 and all the sick people with label 1. Try something like:

```
from glob import glob 
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

#get the filenames for healthy people 
xhealthy = [ fname for fname in glob( 'pathToData/healthy/*' )]

#give healthy people label of 0
yhealthy = [ 0 for i in range( len( xhealthy ))]

#get the filenames of sick people
xsick    = [ fname for fname in glob( 'pathToData/sick/*')]

#give sick people label of 1
ysick    = [ 1 for i in range( len( xsick ))]

#combine the data 
xdata = xhealthy + xsick 
ydata = yhealthy + ysick 

#create the training and test set 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(xdata, ydata, test_size=0.1)
```

Then train your models with X_train, Y_train and test it with X_test, Y_test - keeping in mind that your X_data are just file names that need to still need processing. The more code you post the more people can help with your question.

Comment: Thanks a bundle, Sin. I liked your way than the one mentioned in the tutorial. I tried to fit it in the original code yet still struggling. I pasted the lines that I think my problem is around at the end of my question. The original code from tutorial uses functions for processing a single file then applies it to others using other functions. I'm trying to fit your solution into these functions. Please bear with me; I'm new to all of these :)

Comment: I took a look but I'm not sure I know where you are having problems. The way you have it should align with the rest of the tutorial. Are the train.pkl and the test.pkl not saving correctly?

Comment: Yes, I experienced issues with saving test.pkl. I could solve it by separating the data into train and test manually then labeling each one alone with 0 & 1. It worked well, finally. Thanks a lot for your help. Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by separating the dataset into train and test sets manually and then labelling each set alone. My current dataset is so small, so I will keep looking for a better solution for large datasets once I have the capacity. Provided to close the question.