# Can you help me out in dividing a list of texts?

Tags: neural-network, listdir

I've been working on a tutorial neural network, and I'm currently trying to classify news articles. The problem is, I need to divide my texts into train and test datasets, but I can't find a way to do this.

For example, in my example website, the texts are named like this: `cv100.txt, cv203.txt, cv900.txt` and so on. So the author uses the following code to split these tests into 9:1.

`if filename.startswith('cv9'):` and `if not filename.startswith('cv9'):`

However, for the other task that I'm currently working on, the texts' filenames are listed as follows: `0000Data, 0001Data, ..., 0299Data`.

What I need to do is have the texts from `0000Data` to `0200Data` as the train dataset, and `0200Data` to `0299Data` as the test dataset.

But I've realized that this doesn't work with `filename.startswith('')` method. 
In sum, Filenames like `cv000` ~ `cv999` can be divided into 9:1 by `filename.startswith('cv9')`, but I want to divide filenames such as 
 `0000Data`~`0299Data` into 1:2. However, I can't think of a clever way to divide them.

There must be a good way to figure this out, but I can't think of it, though I've searched and thought a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you book is called *"Deep Learning for Natural Language ProcessingDevelop Deep Learning Models for Natural Language in Python"* and [cover the same](https://books.google.ru/books?id=_pmoDwAAQBAJ), then you just missing right dataset.

Original dataset can be download by the link  http://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/pabo/movie-review-data/review_polarity.tar.gz it contains exactly the same what you described.

```
review_polarity tree
.
├── poldata.README.2.0.md
└── txt_sentoken
    ├── neg
    │   ├── cv000_29416.txt
    │   ├── cv001_19502.txt
    │   ├── cv002_17424.txt
  [...]
    │   ├── cv997_5152.txt
    │   ├── cv998_15691.txt
    │   └── cv999_14636.txt
    └── pos
        ├── cv000_29590.txt
        ├── cv001_18431.txt
        ├── cv002_15918.txt
      [...]
        ├── cv003_11664.txt
        ├── cv004_11636.txt
        ├── cv005_29443.txt
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the data. But I guess I didn't give enough explanation. What I wanted to ask was that, the text files in the task that I am working on do not seem to be divided in the way as the example does. Filenames like 'cv000' ~ 'cv999' can be divided into 9:1 by 'filename.startswith('cv9'), but I want to divide filenames such as 0000Data~0299Data into 1:2. However, I can't think of a clever way to divide them.

Comment: There is not enough info to understand what you want. Book is the same? If yes then what page number or chapter title with you task? Next where did you get the text files for task? Could you describe step by step?

Comment: Hey, it's about you task? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56535955/split-data-into-training-and-testing

Comment: What I meant was, I am working on a task which is similar to the example. The example is what the link is talking about. For me, my task is as follows. First, I have a dataset of news articles divided into 5 sections. I've cleaned, encoded, and padded them. However, I'm stuck at this point where I need to divide the whole dataset into train data and test data. Since the dataset are consisted of text files, named `0000Data`, `0001Data`, ... , `0299Data` for the first section, `1000Data` `1001Data` ... `1299Data` for the second, and `4000Data` `4001Data` ... `4299Data` for the fifth section.

Comment: For each section, I wanted to divide text files into train data and test data, at the ratio of 2:1. So, for the first section textfiles between `0000Data` and `0200Data` would be put into the train data, and files between `0201Data` and `0299Data` in the test data.

According to the example task that I'm referring to, the files were divided at the ratio of 9:1, and it was divided by the code `if filename.startswith('cv9'):`. So textfiles between `cv000` to `cv899` are put in the train data, and `cv900` to `cv999` in the test data.

Comment: However, for my task, I can't think of a code that would separate `0000Data` ~ `0299Data` into train and test data, at the ratio of 2:1. I really thank you for your help. I really appreciate it.